# copy() instance method for copy constructor

Tags: java

As you can see by my code example I'm trying to follow conventions as much as possible. Just wondering if it's common or at least acceptable to create a `copy()` instance method for a class when it has a copy constructor to avoid having to directly call the copy constructor with `new UglyStinkyClassName(instanceName)`, or would doing the following be considered a code smell?

```
public class Foo {

    private String bar = "whatever";

    /** Copy constructor */
    public Foo(Foo that) {
        bar = that.bar;
    }

    /* Instance methods */
    public Foo copy() {
        return new Foo(this);
    }
```

So instead of:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = new Foo(a);
```

I can just go:

```
Foo b = a.copy();
```

Comment: Any reason not to use just "normal" class names for your example? I'd recommend editing to give a more professional (or at least adult) vibe.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem, but I also don't think it's necessary. If it improves readability then go for it. If not, I don't really see a reason to do it because the only real difference is it's a few characters shorter.

Comment: It's more normal to make a copy using a method called `clone()`.  [`clone()` at java T point](https://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning)

Comment: can you please use slightly less vulgar and childish naming?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer thanks but in cases where I want to use a copy constructor instead of using `clone()` I guess I'm just looking for a way to make that approach less verbose

Comment: Yes, I do think you should change it. This is "humour" along the lines of "you smell". It adds nothing to the post, and is purely offputting.

Comment: @JonSkeet almost forgot about this. Changed it. Thanks